# Bootstrap: distribute blank space between elements

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

In the picture below you can see the children are not filling the parent element(red part is the blank space). I tried using `display: 'flex'` in the parent and `alignItems: 'space-between'`, `alignItems: 'left'` in the children but could not achieve what I want.

[image]

What I want:
[image]

My code:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Election({ election }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{election.name}</h1>
      <div style={{background: '#892650', display: 'flex'}}>

        {
          election.candidates.map((candidate, i) => {
            return (
              <Link to='candidate-info'>
                <div className="card" style={{width: '18rem', maxHeight: '600px', alignItems: 'space-between'}}>
                  <img src="/uploads/profile.jpeg" className="card-img-top" alt="..."/>
                  <div className ="card-body">
                  <h5 className ="card-title">{`${candidate.name} ${candidate.surname}`}</h5>
                  <p className ="card-text">{candidate.motto}</p>
                  </div>

                  <div className ="card-body">
                    <button className ="card-link">Card link</button>
                    <button className ="card-link">Another link</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Link>)
          })
        }

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any changes to get it work are welcome. (P.S. bootstrap-way solution is more preferable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`space-between` should be on `justify-content`and `align-items` should be `center`. Try this:

```
<h1>{election.name}</h1>
<div style={{background: '#892650', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}}>
```